# Recently added json language file values are not updated in email blade

Tags: laravel, email, templates, laravel-blade

I send mail as a cron job with Laravel. For this, when I want to use the last value I added in my resources/lang/de.json file in the mail blade template file(resources/views/mails/...blade.php), it gives an output as if such a value is not defined. However, if I use the same key in a blade file I created before, it works without any errors. In addition, the keys that I added to the same file (de.json) in the first time work without errors in the same mail blade file.

Thinking it's some kind of cache situation, I researched and found out that restarting the queue worker might fix the problem. However, both locally and on the server with ssh.
'php artisan queue:restart'
Even though I ran the command, there was no improvement.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not notice changes to your code without being restarted. So, the simplest way to deploy an application using queue workers is to restart the workers during your deployment process. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment

but `php artisan queue:restart` will instruct all queue workers to **gracefully** exit after they finish processing their current job so that no existing jobs are lost. And I see a lot of issues with this command not to solve restart and deploy the worker.

So, Simplest way,

1. try to stop the worker manually (ctrl+C)
2. start the worker again with `php artisan queue:work` again.

might this help.